# Torch.linalg.pinv 3x slower on GPU than numpy.linalg.pinv on CPU

Tags: numpy, torch

**torch.linalg.pinv for CUDA inputs** synchronizes that device with the CPU. However, it seems that the process is not very well optimized and/or does not utilize the GPU properly or is there a smarter way to get this done fast in torch?

Tests on *Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB*, torch version *1.10.1+cu113*:

- **TORCH-GPU:** Elapsed time for matrix inversion in seconds: **21.638889908000237**

  **NUMPY:** Elapsed time for matrix inversion in seconds: **8.481086289999439**

  (TORCH-CPU: Elapsed time for matrix inversion in seconds:
  447.30585926300046)

Code to reproduce the results:

```
from time import process_time

X = torch.rand((256,32,64)).to(device)
Xt = torch.rand((256,32,64))
Xn = np.random.rand(256,32,64)

t1_start = process_time() 
for i in range(0,100):
        Xinv = torch.linalg.pinv(X)
t1_stop = process_time()
print("TORCH-GPU: Elapsed time for matrix inversion in seconds:",
                                         t1_stop-t1_start)


t1_start = process_time()        
for i in range(0,100):
        Xinv = np.array(list(map(np.linalg.pinv,Xn)))
t1_stop = process_time()
print("NUMPY: Elapsed time for matrix inversion in seconds:",
                                         t1_stop-t1_start)


t1_start = process_time() 
for i in range(0,100):
        Xinv = torch.linalg.pinv(Xt)
t1_stop = process_time()
print("TORCH-CPU: Elapsed time for matrix inversion in seconds:",
                                         t1_stop-t1_start)
```

**Note:** For smaller batch-sizes - 64 , 32 - performance benefit of NUMPY decreases as expected, i.e 5.5  vs. 2.3 sec , 2.8 vs. 1.3 secs, respectively.

Comment: Why are you mapping the `numpy` function and convert to `list` to `np.array`?

Comment: It is irrelevant for the main point being made here. Just to get a np.array which is the inverse to Xn.

Answer (score 0):

I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76398157/how-to-apply-the-pseudo-inverse-of-a-matrix-to-n-arrays-with-cupy) with Cupy and it was specifically for the version I was using.

`Torch.linalg.pinv` uses `gesvdj` function from cuSolver which is the [root cause](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/4435).

The SVD Cusolver function has been rewritten, especially to handle broadcasting, and I believe an update to the latest Cuda/PyTorch would show much better performance. It did for me when I updated Cupy.

Comment: Thanks!  Am unfortunately constraint to older version due to other repositories which are used - unless I make all of them work with newer PyTorch versions which seems beyond the scope of my project - it is RL -. Is there another work-around? Im wondering on a general note why is there no wrapper of some sort that allows to import specific functions of newer torch/cuda version -> if its a specific Cu/C++ implementation it could work as a stand alone.